# Can't get LDAP department

Tags: php, ldap

After bind user try to get department list:

```
$filter = "(department=*)";
$justthese = array("*");

$sr = ldap_search($ldap_conn, $ldap_dn, $filter, $justthese);
$info = ldap_get_entries($ldap_conn, $sr);

for($i=0; $i < $info["count"]; $i++)
{
    echo "department: " . $info[$i]["department"][0]."<br>";
}
```

get blank window

Comment: Have you tried just setting `$justthese` to an empty array if `department` is an `ou` you could do `$filter = "(ou=department)";`

Comment: @Cyclone try, no result.

Comment: If you set `$filter = "*"` and `$justthese = array();` do you get any results? If you don't I suspect that you use a invalid `$ldap_dn`. Try printing errors using `print ldap_error($ldap_conn);` and see what the error message say.

Comment: @Cyclone, set this params like you said and don't get any result's. funny, when i'm add `print ldap_error($ldap_conn);` it says Success and i don't get mistakes

Comment: What do you get when you add a printr($info); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the 4th option in `ldap_search()` you are requesting a particular attribute called * which does not exist. 
If you want to request all attributes, use

```
$sr = ldap_search($ldap_conn, $ldap_dn, $filter);
```

Or, if you want a few specific attributes, use

```
$justthese = array("cn","department");
$sr = ldap_search($ldap_conn, $ldap_dn, $filter, $justthese);
```

That should work unless there is another issue like user access rights.